# Can we get notified by email on Sitecore Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if we can receive an email every time one of our questions is answered or receives a comment.

Ideally, I'd like to even receive a notification for every (or for a batch) new question on one of our watched tags.

Do you guys know if that's feasible? I've looked around and can't find anything.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/getting-email-notifications-when-comments-or-answers-are-posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get almost real time notifications if you use RSS feed reader like Feedly or similar and add https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/feeds to list of your feeds.
Then you can set push notifications or email sending for newly arrived "articles".

Take a look here how to set it up:
https://blog.feedly.com/get-notified-of-new-articles-in-your-feedly/

Or just leave Stackexchange opened in your browser and you will see (x) in page title once there is new or updated question

Or just refresh SSE page from time to time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can.

Go to your profile, then "Edit Profile & Settings". Then look for the "Inbox".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark. So that means that we can't receive real-time updates, it's only possible to have those in a batch of 3 hours activity?